# Python property setter not being called

Tags: python-3.x, properties

In a class I have two property methods with each their own setters. The x setter (https://github.com/ertpoi/me/blob/main/engine.py#L182) is being called as expected when I change it's value, but the y setter (https://github.com/ertpoi/me/blob/main/engine.py#L196) is not being called at all upon changes to the y method. Can some one see where the problem is happening? I call the setters at the end of the file:

```py
m=MChar("clefs.C")
m.x = True
m.y = True
```

which prints only:

```
>>>>>>>>>SetX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overidden the y setter at [line 212](https://github.com/ertpoi/me/blob/main/engine.py#L212)

```
@y.setter
    def y(self, newy): pass
```